# How to align elements and add icon to bootstrap li

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I don't know how to center icon with the text. I have SVG + text. I can do it with plain CSS(flex-box) but I have to use bootstrap. Also, I want to center text, so it will be centered as other parts of the webpage, I want it to be aligned vertically

I have this:[image]

I want to get this:
[image]

I have tried different solutions but did not come up with a good idea.
So the questions are:

- How to make text to be centered to the left so it looks centered?
- How to aligned svg icon with the text?

thanks

```
        <section class="perks">
        <img src="./media/blueCircle.svg" alt="" />
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col perksFirst">Perks of Meetlete</div>
            <div class="w-100"></div>

            <div class="row perksList">
                <div class="col">Access to our secure video platform!</div>
                <div class="col">
                <img src="./media/2.svg" alt="" />Calls are executed through our
                App!
                </div>
                <div class="w-100"></div>

                <div class="col">Metelete calls take place on your time!</div>
                <div class="col">None of your information is shared!</div>
                <div class="w-100"></div>

                <div class="col">Build loyalty with your fans!</div>
                <div class="col">Make lifetime memories!</div>
                <div class="w-100"></div>

                <div class="col">Earn up to 10x more than other platforms!</div>
                <div class="col">Meetlete calls are timed!</div>
            </div>
            <div class="w-100"></div>
            <div class="col">
                <button class="earlyAccess btn">Early access</button>
                <div class="launchDate">Launching 2/14/21!</div>
            </div>
            </div>
            
        </section>


        .perks {
        display: flex;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 310px;
        position: relative;
        }

        .perks .earlyAccess {
        margin-top: 117px;
        }
        .perks img {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: -50%;
        }

            .perks .row {
            justify-content: center;
            }

            .perksList {
            max-width: 860px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            }

            .perksList .col {
            font-weight: 600;
            font-size: 18px;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            display: flex !important;
            text-align: start;
            margin-top: 26px;
            }

            .perksFirst {
            margin-bottom: 77px;
            font-size: 24px;
            font-weight: 700;
            }

            .launchDate {
            font-weight: 700;
            font-size: 18px;
            margin-top: 26px;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to align icons with the text you can put them together in a 
Or you use bootstrap grid https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/. You could use this easily to render it all dynamically, by putting your text in a list.

You can use text-align: center on the outer div (container) to center all. then text-align left in the inner one (perklist) in case this turns your text all left aligned.

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.heading {
  text-align: center;
  padding: .5rem;
}

.heading h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.card {
  background: whitesmoke;
  padding: 2rem;
  border: darkgrey
}

span {
  display: flex;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-top: 1rem;
}

span img {
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 2rem;
}

span a {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 2rem;
  padding-left: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Solution By Tarak</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="new.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xl-1"></div>
      <div class="card col-xl-10 col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="heading col-12">
            <h3>Perks of Meetlete</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xl-6 col-md-12">
            <span><img src="./test-tubes.svg" /><a>Access to our secure video platform!</a></span>
            <span><img src="./test-tubes.svg" /><a>Metelete calls take place on your time!</a></span>
            <span><img src="./test-tubes.svg" /><a>Build loyalty with your fans!</a></span>
            <span><img src="./test-tubes.svg" /><a>Earn up to 10x more than other platforms!</a></span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xl-6 col-md-12">
            <span><img src="./test-tubes.svg" /><a>Calls are executed through our App!</a></span>
            <span><img src="./test-tubes.svg" /><a>None of your information is shared!</a></span>
            <span><img src="./test-tubes.svg" /><a>Make lifetime memories!</a></span>
            <span><img src="./test-tubes.svg" /><a>Meetlete calls are timed!</a></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

height of span img == line-height of span a (for it to be inline center)

change svg of your choice.

play with styles.